# Difference between open file & open STDIN, when to use each

Tags: bash, text-processing, stdin

In very lot of answers, mainly about `text-processing` commands, I saw commands such as `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, among other, being used with STDIN and the simple open of a file

e.g.

```
$ sed -e 's|foo|bar|g' file # open file
$ sed -e 's|foo|bar|g' <file # open STDIN
```

or

```
$ grep 'PATTERN' file # open file
$ grep 'PATTERN' <file # open STDIN
```

In a personal, I use the open file method always, but I want to know when and when not to use them, also what's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the need. Here's a case where using filenames or piping from stdin makes a difference.

```
bash-4.1$ cat /etc/passwd /etc/group | wc -l
128
bash-4.1$ wc -l /etc/passwd /etc/group
  49 /etc/passwd
  79 /etc/group
 128 total
bash-4.1$
```

Also, standard input tends to not be very `lseek(3)`able, so if an application needs a file descriptor it can seek on (e.g. to rewind back to the beginning), that would probably rule out using standard input with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in terms of the output.

`$ grep 'PATTERN' file` will open the file specified in argument 2 and will search for the pattern.

`$ grep 'PATTERN' <file` will read the contents of `file` into `STDIN` (one of bash's features), and will pipe `STDIN` into `grep`.

I am not sure if there are exact benefits of one or the other, but I would continue using the former instead of the latter.

The latter is redundant, just as `cat file | grep 'PATTERN'` and `cat file | sed -e 's|foo|bar|g'` are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There are instances in which the two are not exactly equivalent, like:

```
$ wc -l ./script.sh
4948 ./script.sh
$ wc -l <./so
4948
```

In the first instance `wc` knew which file was being processed and printed the name of the file with the count of lines. In the second, the command `wc` does not know what file is processing, it is an anonymous input.

In the specific command of your example with grep:

```
$ grep 'PATTERN' file
$ grep 'PATTERN' <file
```

There is no difference in the output. But with this, there is (if there is a match):

```
$ grep -H 'PATTERN' file
$ grep -H 'PATTERN' <file
```

Also, in the case of the redirection `<file`, it is the shell which is doing the reading of the file, that might also have consequences on speed or size of buffering (for different commands).

Comment: The shell does not read `file`. The shell merely opens `file` then manipulates file descriptors (e.g. using `dup2`) so that  `file` is available on descriptor 0 (standard in). The shell will then `exec` `grep`, replacing itself and allowing `grep` to read standard input as it pleases.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is mostly in who opens the file. This may be important for [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor#File_descriptors_as_capabilities) -- the shell may have privileges that the launched program does not have.

Using the STDIN method implies inheritance of the stream to the whole process tree created by the launched program. That may be useful in certain cases.

With the *open file* method, the launched program knows the filename more readily. Programs taking the filename route are likely to use the filename in their output, and the filename route may differ in other ways like performance: Programs often assume only basic stream access for STDIN (no seeking, no mmapability), and seekability for filename arguments.